# How to access other UI components

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I would like to exchange data and / or call methods of another UI component. How can I access another UI component in Magento 2 knockout JS ?

Answer (score 15):

List all components

```
var registry = require('uiRegistry');
registry.filter(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key);
    // console.log(value); 
});
```

Get a specific one

```
registry.get(
    'checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.paypal_express.checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.paypal_express.messages'
);
```

This is meant for debugging and might not be the best way to communicate between components.

From: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get all the components:

> require('uiRegistry').get(function(c){ console.log(c.name); });