# Bind shipping address data in custom form in new checkout step

Tags: checkout, custom, knockoutjs, shipping-address, magento2.2.0

I have added a new step in one-page checkout after the shipping step.
I need to fetch the data from the shipping form and bind it to the new form.
The code for above is as following.

age-verify-view.js

```
define(
        [
            'ko',
            'uiComponent',
            'underscore',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
        ],
        function (
                ko,
                Component,
                _,
                quote,
                stepNavigator
                ) {
            'use strict';
            return Component.extend({
                defaults: {
                    template: 'Ktpl_LexisNexis/age-verify-view'
                },

                //add here your logic to display step,
                isVisible: ko.observable(false),

                /**
                 *
                 * @returns {*}
                 */
                initialize: function () {
                    this._super();
                    // register your step
                    stepNavigator.registerStep(
                            'verify_age',
                            null,
                            'Verify Age',
                            this.isVisible,
                            _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                            15
                            );

                    return this;
                },

                /**
                 * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
                 * during checkout.
                 */
                navigate: function () {
                    this.isVisible(true);
                },

                /**
                 * @returns void
                 */
                navigateToNextStep: function () {
                    if (stepNavigator.isProcessed('verify_age')) {
                        stepNavigator.next();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
);
```

age-verify-form.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Ktpl_LexisNexis/js/action/VerifyAction'
], function ($, ko, Component, quote, checkoutData, customerData, verifyAction) {
    'use strict';
    var isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    var isVarified = ko.observable(false);
    var dob = ko.observable(new Date());
    var countryData = ko.observable(customerData.get('directory-data'));
    var shippingAddress = ko.observable(quote.shippingAddress());
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Ktpl_LexisNexis/age-verify-form'
        },
        isLoading: isLoading,
        isVerified: isVarified,
        dob: dob,
        countryData : countryData(),
        shippingAddress: shippingAddress,

        //  address: address(),
        /**
         * 
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        verify: function () {
            var form = '#age-verify-form',
                    formDataArray = $(form).serializeArray(),
                    verifyFormData = {};
            if (this.validate(form)) {
                formDataArray.forEach(function (entry) {
                    verifyFormData[entry.name] = entry.value;
                });
                isLoading(true);
                verifyAction(verifyFormData,isLoading,isVarified);
            }
        },
        /**
         * 
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        cancel: function () {
            if (this.validate()) {
                isLoading(true);
            }
        },
        /**
         * 
         * @param {type} form
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function (form) {
            return $(form).validation() && $(form).validation('isValid');
        }
    });
});
```

age-verify-view.html

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Verify Age'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
        <div id="age-verify" class="age-verify-form">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('age-verify-form') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

age-veirfy-form.html

```
<div class="age-verify-option-content" data-role="content">
    <form class="form age-verify-form"  id="age-verify-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="fieldset address" id="co-age-verify" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
            <pre data-bind="text: shippingAddress()"></pre>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="firstname">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'First Name'">First Name</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input-text" 
                           type="text"
                           name="firstname"
                           id="firstname"
                           title="First Name"
                           data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('First Name')} "/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="lastname">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Last Name'">Last Name</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input-text" 
                           type="text"
                           name="lastname"
                           id="lastname"
                           title="Last Name"
                           data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Last Name')} "/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="dob">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Date of Birth'">Date of Birth</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="dob"
                           id="dob"
                           title="Date of Birth"
                           data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                           data-bind="value: dob,datepicker: dob,datePickeroptions: {
                                        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',
                                        changeMonth: true,
                                        changeYear: true,
                                        maxDate: new Date(),
                                        datePickerPlaceholder: 'dd/M/yy' 
                                       }" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="street-1">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Address'">Address</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="street[0]"
                           id="street-1"
                           title="Street Address"
                           data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Street Address')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="street-2">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Address (Line 2)'">Address (Line 2)</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="street[1]"
                           id="street-2"
                           title="Address (Line 2)"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Address (Line 2)')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="city">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'City'">City</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="city"
                           id="city"
                           title="City"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('City')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="state">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'State'">State</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="state"
                           id="state"
                           title="State"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('State')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="postcode">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Zip/Postal Code'">Zip/Postal Code</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="postcode"
                           id="postcode"
                           title="Zip/Postal Code"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Zip/Postal Code')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="country">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Country'">Country</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="country"
                           id="country"
                           title="Country"
                           data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Country')}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
               <div class="primary">
                  <!-- ko ifnot: isVerified() -->
                  <button class="action action-apply" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Verify Age'), click: verify">
                     <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Verify Age'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                  </button>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <!-- ko if: isVerified() -->
                  <button class="action action-cancel" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Cancel Verify'), click: cancel">
                     <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Cancel Verify'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                  </button>
                  <!-- /ko -->
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As can be seen, i have used `quote.shippingAddress()` as a `ko.observable`, but when the shipping address is already there and selected from the list rather then filling the form, it returns `null`, how can we make sure that we always have the shippingAddress available in the age-verify-form.js?

Also i am not sure how to bind the data from `ko.observable(quote.shippingAddress())` in the html file for the form.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188579/how-to-access-other-ui-components helps ... just an idea...

Comment: @Alex i tried this, but it still gives undefined